# Disable Bigcommerce new account registration email

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there anyway we can disable the default Bigcommerce email for account registration and newsletter subscription ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable emails through a bit of a workaround, but these do not have store settings to disable. You will need to go to Store Settings > Misc and set your own SMTP server to route the mail through or a dummy SMTP server that doesn't send any mail. You would have to configure the server from there to only pass on the desired emails to customers.

Comment: But this will stop all other emails as well , we only need to disable account registration email and newsletter subscription email and need to send those emails from third party

Comment: Right and I am saying that there isn't an alternative to my suggestion until BigCommerce releases a feature that enables you to manage those particular emails (as one presently doesn't exist).

Comment: Will it work if we rename the email template  ,so that it will skip sending that email or will it stop executions when email template do not found ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.